# Visual Studio doesnt find any references or packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

VS doesnt find any references:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwKGP.png)

I tried reinstalling them with nuget, but it didnt work out. I cleaned the solution and rebuild it and deleted the nuget cache. Since none of this worked, I try to add a reference per hand to the path of the dlls I found, but it seems like all of them have the version 0.0.0.0, which doesnt feel correct, but Im not sure about this.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by myself. If anyone faces the same problem and already tried

- -cleaning the nuget cache
- -cleaning and rebuilding the project
- -repairing Visual Studio
- -deleting the package directory and downloading packages again
- -adding the dlls per direct path

I solved this by just pulling the old csproj-file from github and replacing it in the new code. Whatever caused this non-sense, it seems to be located in the csproj-file.